# Notify user while running Simple Workflow

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I´m using a simple workflow, to "**Approve**" or "**Disapprove**" documents on my site.

The problems is that when an user click´s on **Approve**, or **Disappove**, it looks like the click doesn´t work, the workflow starts running in background, and doesn´t notify the user. Sometimes he click´s again on the button, causing some errors.

Is there a way to notify the user to wait with some progress bar, gif or anyway?

Comment: what is your alfresco version? Because I noticed in Alfresco 5, once the user clicked Approved or Reject button, all the buttons will be disabled except Cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add progress bar from the client side JavaScript file from where it is making Ajax call to repository.

Comment: In this case, using the default SimpleWorkflow, where can I program this? This workflow is provided by alfresco.

Comment: You need to use Client side javascript to attach / show the progress dialog box.